# Disable the Yellow Popup in InternetExplorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am saving a file to particular folder but I get an IE popup asking "Do you want to open or save (filename.png) from localhost?"

Is this possible to disable this manually?

[image]

Comment: So, what would you want to happen instead?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1316053/how-can-i-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt-for-mp3-files

Answer (score 0):

[There are many posts on internet](https://search.lilo.org/searchweb.php?q=avoid+%22do+you+want+to+open+or+save%22).

Basically 2 solution:

- change the registry for specific files, like tried [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1316053/how-can-i-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt-for-mp3-files), however unsuccessfully.

## Manually change IE settings  [Internet Explorer 10 or 11]:

- click on a file of the type you want to open automatically next time.   This will give you the Open/Save prompt.
- Select the Save option.
- Then in Internet Explorer click <kbd>Tools</kbd> + View <kbd>Downloads</kbd> option
- You will see a popup containing the file that you just downloaded.
- <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on the file
- In the options presented, make sure to **un-check the option labeled**: ***Always ask before opening this type of file***