# How can I disable "Do you want to open or save this file?” prompt for .mp3 files in IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE11 for my AutoHotKey scripts.I want to disable “Do you want to open or save this file?” download prompt.

I tried following things.

1-)Find the correct registry value for.mp3

```
C:\Users\q>assoc.mp3
.mp3=WMP11.AssocFile.MP3
```

2-)Create Regedit key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Shell \ AttachmentExecute \ {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

3-)Create zero length binary-registry value named .mp3=WMP11.AssocFile.MP3

But still, IE 11 asks for "Do you want to open or save this file?”

```
My IE version is: `11.371.16299.0`
My operating system:Windows 10
```

How can I fix that problem?

Note that IE 11 has not “`Always ask before opening this type of file`” check-box.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to see this answer but I don't think that it's possible anymore.  I personally still use Shoutcast to listen to radio stations and this *issue* with IE11 is one of the most annoying issues that Microsoft has created (on purpose).  All of the methods you described in your question use to work but they have since then disabled them all.

> [rant]
>
> Microsoft seems to think it's their job to police the PC you use.  So
>   they made the decision to force you to choose open or save EVERY time
>   you click a link with that file type.
>
> You would think to have to go into the download manager and
>   RIGHT-click to get to the option needed to make it a permanent action
>   would be sufficient enough to let Microsoft know that we know what the
>   hell we are doing.
>
> And they wonder why we want to use other browsers...
>
> [/rant]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try IE Manual configuration for MP3 (from [here](https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/)).

- go to option - downloads
- right-click on a MP3 file
- uncheck *Always ask before opening this type of file*

Hope it helps.
J

Comment: Thanks but this option is not available for ie 11 and ie 10.And windows 10 only support ie 11.